# Java Runtime exec not working for redis delete query

Tags: java, redis

I am trying to run Redis script from java runtime but this is not working. can someone help with this?

```
String pattern  =   "a*";
String command  =   "redis-cli --scan --pattern "+pattern+" | xargs redis-cli del";
Runtime rt  =   Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr  =   rt.exec(command.split(" "));
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: I am getting an empty response while I have a key in the redis as abc. When I am running this same command in the terminal it works.

Comment: " I am getting an empty response "

How do you read the response? I wonder it has something to do with the delay of response from Runtime. You might be accessing the result way before the result is recieved.

Comment: I am reading it from the Process input stream. I guess you should have a look at that method where you get the response as an input stream. And even if i am accessing the result way before but the command must have executed on the environment which is not the case. I hope my answer has helped you understand more.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.